# Why has ViewModelProviders been deprecated?

Tags: android, viewmodel

Why has ViewModelProviders been deprecated? I want to understand the reasons this class has been deprecated. Is it because google used Service Locator design pattern ( so called anti-pattern ) in it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/lifecycle-extensions/src/main/java/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.java#60), you'll see that the `ViewModelProviders` is nothing but a wrapper around a new constructor for `ViewModelProvider`:

```
public static ViewModelProvider of(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    return new ViewModelProvider(fragment);
}
```

So, as per the deprecation message, just use `new ViewModelProvider(this)` instead of `ViewModelProviders.of(this)`.

Comment: It makes sense!